# how to trigger a function call on click of download option in audio tag in html

Tags: html, reactjs

I am using a simple audio tag which has a download option. I want to keep a track of how many downloads have been done. which event handler will do my job here ?? and how to use that event handler ??

I have a fully functional back end API ready the problem is I am not able to figure out how to call a function on click of download here so that I can call my API further ??

I have attached my code here .

```
    <audio style={{ height: '30px' }} controls>
    <source
        src={renderHTML(lectureDetails.audio_link)}
        type="audio/mpeg"
    />
   </audio>
```

Answer (score 1):

As there is no clear event to distinguish download by button in a cross-browsers-fashion, my advice is to remove the download option from `<audio />`:

```
<audio controls id="audio" controlsList="nodownload">
```

then add a button near your `<audio />` that enable the user to download the audio and track its behavior by listener:

- you can use "click" event
- you can trigger an XHR call and track progress/complete event